# Найти количество способов соединить точки

Tags: python, python-3.x, графы, комбинаторика

Задача: написать функцию, которая принимает на вход целое число точек и возвращает количество способов соединить эти точки. Отсутствие соединения между точками тоже считается за способ. Для 8 точек - ответ 64, для 2 точек - 2, для 3 точек - 8:

[image: для 3 точек ответ 8]

Решается как-то через графы. Проверка: для 991 точки - ответ 948726690

Прошу прощения, я вероятно недопонял условия. Вот сам текст исходной задачи:

> Given a number of vertices, determine the number of ways these
> vertices can form a graph. The graph may be disjoint, so it is not
> necessary to connect all vertices.The answer may be very large, return
> its value modulo (10**9+7).    Note: Two ways of drawing edges are
> considered different if at least one pair of vertices has a different
> connection or the number of edges is different.

Спасибо за эти решения:

> раз просто кол-во, то пусть они стоят по кругу. я думаю, что число
> ребер n=int(X*(X-1)/2), и тогда sum(f(n)/f(n-k)/f(k) for k in
> range(n+1)) – splash58 2 часа назад
>
> Существует 2^(n*(n-1)/2) произвольных графов с n вершинами. Есть
> ощущение, что задача недопоставлена. – MBo 1 час назад

Осталась проблема переполнения стека для больших чисел на входе функции, как я понимаю, надо как-то разбивать вычисление на этапы и на каждом этапе выполнять операцию вида res = res % M, где M = 1000000000 + 7

Вот такое решение работает, но не проходит по лимиту времени:

```
MOD = (10**9 + 7)

def function(n):
    
    level = int((n * (n - 1) / 2))
    res = (2 ** level) % MOD
    return int(res)
```

Comment: 64 -  это для 4х

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, пересечения соединяющих линий допускается? (кнопка "править")

Comment: Решается через комбинаторику, а не через графы.

Comment: раз просто кол-во, то пусть они стоят по кругу. я думаю, что число ребер n=int(X*(X-1)/2), и тогда sum(f(n)/f(n-k)/f(k) for k in range(n+1))

Comment: Существует `2^(n*(n-1)/2)` произвольных графов с n вершинами. Есть ощущение, что задача недопоставлена.

Comment: Количество **планарных графов** с n вершинами `1, 2, 8, 64, 1023, 32071, 1823707, 163947848, 20402420291, 3209997749284, 604611323732576, 131861300077834966, 32577569614176693919,`, т.е. `для 991 точки - ответ 948726690` тут тоже никак...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В графе с `n` вершинами `n*(n-1)/2` возможных рёбер, каждое может присутствовать или отсутствовать, отсюда число возможных графов

```
M = 2**(n*(n-1)/2)
```

При нахождении большой степени по модулю можно использовать встроенные в Python средства - `pow` с тремя аргументами вычисляет нужную величину быстро (видимо, с использованием алгоритма бинарного возведения в степень)

```
MOD = (10**9 + 7)

def funct(n):
    level = n * (n - 1) // 2
    res = pow(2, level, MOD)
    return res
```